# Docker: Dockerize a service that requires mmdb files in /opt/my-service/db folder

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a service that requires mmdb files (maxmind db file format) in a particular location **/opt/my-service/db**

Locally I am able to run the service if I set up my system by copying required mmdb files to the "**/opt/my-service/db**" folder.

What should I do for the docker? I tried copying the files by creating same file location in the dockerfile ( NOT working) :

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8  

EXPOSE 8080

COPY ./my-service/target/my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

cmd mkdir -p /opt/my-service/db

copy ./my-service/src/test/resources/* /opt/ipgeo/db/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Is this how it should be done? 
OR a container should be created? If yes, how?

Comment: you should only have one CMD per dockerfile. try to use RUN instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd mkdir` will not be run to build the Dockerfile.
So, replace your Dockerfile by this one:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8  
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./my-service/target/my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
RUN mkdir -p /opt/my-service/db
COPY ./my-service/src/test/resources/* /opt/ipgeo/db/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

**Moreover, are you sure that /opt/my-service/db and /opt/ipgeo/db should not be the same string, in this Dockerfile?**

If so, the correct Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8  
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./my-service/target/my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
RUN mkdir -p /opt/my-service/db
COPY ./my-service/src/test/resources/* /opt/my-server/db/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```